# Elasticsearch Single word to Multi word synonym issue

Tags: elasticsearch

Im currently using Elasticsearch 5.5.1 (unfortunately cant upgrade at the moment). And having an issue with multi word synonyms, where searching for just a single word is bringing back unexpected results.

I have setup my index like so

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "my_synonym_graph": {
                        "type": "synonym_graph",
                        "synonyms": [
                            "lawrence weaver, colonel trench, frederick bruce"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "my_synonym_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "type":"custom",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "my_synonym_graph"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "document": {
            "properties": {
                "fulltextdata": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "english",
                    "fields": {
                        "synonym": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "my_synonym_analyzer",
                            "search_analyzer":"my_synonym_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add some documents

```
PUT /test_index/document/1
{
  "id": "1",
  "fulltextdata": "frederick bruce is here" 
}
PUT /test_index/document/2
{
  "id": "2",
  "fulltextdata": "colonel trench is here" 
}
PUT /test_index/document/3
{
  "id": "23",
  "fulltextdata": "lawrence weave is here" 
}
```

When a search is performed using a `multi_match` like so

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "type":"phrase",
                        "query": "lawrence",
                        "fields": [
                            "fulltextdata",
                            "fulltextdata.synonym"
                        ],
                        "boost": 2.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "type":"phrase",
                        "query": "weaver",
                        "fields": [
                            "fulltextdata",
                            "fulltextdata.synonym"
                        ],
                        "boost": 2.0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This comes back with the three documents that is expected. However if the search was just a single word i.e.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "type":"phrase",
                        "query": "lawrence",
                        "fields": [
                            "fulltextdata",
                            "fulltextdata.synonym"
                        ],
                        "boost": 2.0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect there to just be a single result, however all three documents are returned.

Am I missing something obvious, or just misunderstanding how the synonym filter is working.

I have tried changing the type of search, and tried changing different rules in the synonym set, but to no real result. I found this [Auto Phrase](https://kaushik-jeyaraman.medium.com/elasticsearch-handling-multi-word-phrase-and-synonyms-76534e3aeed6) that talks about auto phrasing but I wasnt able to see any results.

Any help is appreciated.